# Not able to detect error in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am new with stored procedure.

I have written the following stored procedure:

```
create proc sp_TaxBrock
as
BEGIN
   Declare @intTax int,@intBrockrage int,@sum int
   set @intTax = (select Tax from partyRegister where partyCode = '0L036')
   set @intBrockrage = (select brockrage from partyRegister where partyCode = '0L036')

   set @sum = @intTax+@intBrockrage

   select @sum
   print @sum
   /*print @intTax+@intBrockrage;*/
go
```

It is causing this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_TaxBrock, Line 12
>   Incorrect syntax near '@sum'.

Not able to find what is mistake.

I tried by adding semicolons (`;`) at different locations, but still the error is same.

Please help me.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Also: this assigment: `set @intTax = (select Tax from partyRegister where partyCode = '0L036')` can be written much simpler as `select @intTax = Tax from partyRegister where partyCode = '0L036'` if you can be **sure** that only one row will ever match this criteria

Comment: @marc_s yeah, thanx i will keep in mind these things. Thank You.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add an `end` before `go`.

```
create proc sp_TaxBrock
as
BEGIN

  Declare @intTax int,@intBrockrage int,@sum int
  set @intTax =(select Tax from partyRegister where partyCode='0L036')
  set @intBrockrage=(select brockrage from partyRegister where partyCode='0L036')

  set @sum = @intTax+@intBrockrage

  select @sum
  print @sum
/*print @intTax+@intBrockrage;*/
end
go
```